# regex code doesnt work on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

i have a code like:

```
    function rgb2hex(rgb) {
        rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
        function hex(x) {
            return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }
        return hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
    }
```

it simply get a rgb code and converts it into hex. It works on all browsers (on IE9 as well), but not on IE7 or IE8

Where is the problem?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is *never* a good error description. Please describe what exactly goes wrong, what error messages you get, how the results differ from what you expected...

Comment: Have you tried making your Regex case insensitive?

Comment: It works for me on IE7 (emulated with IE9).

Comment: Works fine in IE8, what is the exact string which fails?

Comment: Which facts speak for defining a function within a function?

Answer (score 2):

You do not give any indication as to what results you actually get in IE < 9 (some example input and result strings that you consider to be failing would've been particularly helpful) so all I can do is take a guess:

You are using `parseInt()`, and the implementation of `parseInt()` changed in IE9. (Actually, it changed in ECMAScript5, but IE didn't catch up with this until version 9.)

As indicated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/x53yedee(v=vs.94).aspx

> Starting in Internet Explorer 9 standards mode, the parseInt function does not treat a string that has a prefix of '0' as octal.

Obviously this means that if your rgb values do contain leading zeros you will get different results depending on the browser version. Presumably you want to treat the numbers as base 10; this is easily fixed by changing your `hex()` function:

```
return ("0" + parseInt(x, 10).toString(16)).slice(-2);
// add radix here --------^
```

If your rgb values do not contain leading zeros, well, how about you update your question to include all the information?

Answer (score 0):

I have a faster and universal solution ever :)

```
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
      rgb = [].slice.call(arguments).join(",").match(/\d+/g);
      var hex,l;
      l=( hex = ( (rgb[0] << 16 ) + ( rgb[1] << 8 ) + +rgb[2] ).toString(16) ).length;
         while( l++ < 6 )
             hex="0"+hex
      return hex;
    }
```

Yo're able to calling with:

```
rgb2hex( "rgb(0,0,255)" ); // "0000ff"
rgb2hex( "55,32,255" ); // "3720ff"
rgb2hex( 255, 30, 40 ); // "ff1e28"
```

And:

```
function hexToRgb( hex ) {

    var rgb = parseInt( hex.match(/[a-f\d]{6}/gi), 16);

       return[
           ( rgb >> 16 ) & 255,
           ( rgb >> 8 ) & 255,
           rgb & 255
       ]
}

hexToRgb( "#ffffff" ); // [ 255, 255, 255 ]
hexToRgb( "ffffff" ); // [ 255, 255, 255 ]
```

demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ld5Gs/